# Sending Mail Using SMTP is not working for Yahoo or anyother mail

Tags: iphone, ios, email, ios4, smtp

I am using SMTP to send email from iphone.
It is working fine if i am using gmail account but when i try to do same thing with yahoo mail,it is not working, i have changed the "relayHost" but not working.
Any one have idea on how to send Email without mailComposerSheet that will run for all Email Services.

Comment: Are you talking about `MFMailComposeViewController`? That's using the same settings the built-in Mail app on your iPhone is using. If you can't send through Yahoo mail from your own app, I bet you can't send Yahoo mail through your Mail.app either.  Check your SMTP settings.

Comment: If i am using MFMailComposerViewController it works fine for all mail servises but when i use the SMTP code from the following link


http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/


i can not send Email usimg 
smtp.mail.yahoo.com
 and port no - 995, 465

If u have any idea what are the setting for yahoo plz help me.